# is it possible to insert a single value to a datatable cell?

Tags: c#

I have a datatable with 5 columns and 4 rows with no data in them.

is it possible to insert a single value to a datatable cell? or do u have to insert data while creating the row ( example dTable.Rows.Add("My Name"); )

Comment: _Way_ to few information. E.g. "which database technology?", "which database access technology?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
mydatatable.Rows[0]["columnname"] = "value" // Provided column is string type
```

This will add only value in a particular cell.

Comment: Thank you! cant believe it was that simple :)

Comment: i tried dtable.rows[0].cells[0] = "value";  and dtable.rows[0].itemarray[0] = "value";  both didnt work ;/